# Solve Calculate the Distance of point x and y given methods and class

Tags: java

Hi please could anyone offer to help. I was told to randomly generate a few Line objects and display the Line info. For example, a method generates and returns a random integer; a method generates and returns the two random points.

```
class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;
   
  public Point(){}

  public Point(int x, int y){
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
  }
  public Point(Point p){
      //copy constructor?
  }
  public double distance(Point p){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
  public double getDistance(Point p){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
  public int getX(){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
  public int getY(){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
  public void set(int x, int y)
  //what codes should be in here
  }
  public String toString(){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
}
```

was also given a class line to do some coding in it but wasn't sure exactly what to key in

```
class Line{
  public Line(){
  }
  public Line(Point p1,Point p2){
  }
  public Line(Line aline){
  }
  public double getDistance(){
  }
  public Point getP1(){
  }
  public Point getP2(){
  }
  public void set(Point p1,Point p2){
  }
  public String toString(){
  }
```

and under main class,

```
class Main{
  public static int getInt(){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
  public static void getTwoPoints(Point p1,Point p2){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
  public static void main(String[]args){
  //what codes should be in here
  }
}

The output should be like this,
Set 1
//Given Point(66,36)
//Given Point(78,-83)
//Line (Point(66,36),Point(78,-83),distance=119.6035)
//--------------------
//Set 2
//Given Point(-13,90)
//Given Point(39,16)
//Line (Point(-13,90),Point(39,16),distance=90.4434)
```

Comment: Read about *getters* and *setters*.

Comment: For distance check out  the `Math.hypot()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't if I understand what you have to do...does this make sense to you?

```
class Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

  public Point(int x, int y){
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
  }

  public double distance(Point p){
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(this.x - p.x), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(this.y - p.y), 2));
  }

  public int getX(){
    return this.x;
  }

  public int getY(){
    return this.y;
  }

  public void set(int x, int y) {}
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "(" + this.x ", " + this.y + ")";
  }
}
```

```
class Line{
    Point p1;
    Point p2;

    public Line(Point p1,Point p2){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }

    public double getDistance(){
        return this.p1.distance(this.p2);
    }
    public Point getP1(){
        return this.p1;
    }
    public Point getP2(){
        return this.p2;
    }
    public void set(Point p1,Point p2){
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "[" this.p1.toString() + ", " + this.p2.toString() + "]"
    }
}
```

```
class Main{
    protected static final Random random = new Random();

    public static int getInt(){
        return random.nexInt();
    }
    public static Line getLine(){
        return new Line(new Point(getInt(), getInt()), new Point(getInt(), getInt()));
    }
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println(getLine().toString());
        System.out.println(getLine().toString());
    }
}
```